# Best Method of Displaying Time in Android Timer

Tags: java, android, xml

I was curious and could use a bit of help with a Timer app I'm working on for Android. Is it a good idea to just use one single TextView that displays the time, or would it be better to use three individual TextViews (one for hours, minutes, and seconds)? I'll be using a Number Picker Dialog to set the values, but I am a bit confused how that will work if I just use one TextView.

Thanks for any repsonses.

Also, I can't use Timer, Chronometer, CountdownTimer, or Digital Clock View for this timer. Restricted to Asynch Tasks, Handlers, Threads. Professors orders.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chronometer class of android API. It has methods for start and stop Chronometer. The XML View also available. also you will be able to pause and resume the Chronometer.
Three fields available (H:MM:SS) for timer in Chronometer.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have added that I actually found out from my professor the other day that we can't use the Timer, Chronometer, CountdownTimer, or the Digital Clock View. He wants us to update UI from threads/AsynchTasks/Handlers. Do you maybe have any alternate tips on it with those parameters?